# For which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the set S a linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $P_{2}(\mathbf{R})$ the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to two.

Define the subset:

$S:= \{ p(x) \in P_{2}(\mathbf{R}) : P(0) = \alpha, P'(0)=\beta \}$

P' denotes first derivative of P.
Im asked to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make $S$ a subspace.

Since the zero polynomial must be in $S$, I find that $\alpha = 0$,
I suspect that $\beta$ = 0 too, but I cant quite see it, and therefore justify it.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is $P'(0)$ when $P$ is the zero polynomial?

Comment: @geetha290km Zero... so...

Comment: So $\beta=0$ too.

Comment: Yes.  But you have to prove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(x)=\beta x$. But for any non-zero $a$, the element $aP(x)$ is not in the set unless $\beta=0$.